# Is there any query builder for InfluxDB in Golang?

Tags: go, influxdb, influxdb-go

I am new to InfluxDB and trying to do query in my local InfluxDB using Go client.

The [parameterised](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-go#parametrized-queries) version of this doesn't seem to work as intended and they mention it is only for the "cloud". Is there any way to have a proper query builder for Go without having to do it manually myself?